# Export latex-pdf and loose references: how to fix?

Tags: org-mode

When I export a org file in latex and generate the pdf (recompiling after a modification in the org file), the pdf file loose the references to section and citation. Here is the line in my .emacs

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process 
  '("latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode' -bibtex -f -pdf %f"))
```

I have to manually delete the bbl file and compile again so that the pdf shows the right references. How to I do that automatically?

Comment: This bothers me as well, but since this is just a list of shell commands, I ended up adding another entry to this lists, which removes the generated bibliography, though I'd be interested to learn a better way to deal with it.

Comment: When you have files needing built, depending on other files being changed, a `Makefile` is the obvious solution. You could probably even coerse `org` to use `compile` for the export process.

Comment: How should I modify the code above so that when exporting from org-mode it rebuild the references? I didn't quite get from your answer.

Comment: Here is what I did `(setq org-latex-pdf-process (quote ("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f")))`. It works perfectly. If you guys know a better solution let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Diogo Please consider posting your solution as an answer so this post doesn't show up in the list of "Unanswered" questions anymore. You'll even be able to [accept your own answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (after 48 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did (setq org-latex-pdf-process (quote ("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f"))). It works perfectly

Also, there are some other possibilities that may work better for some situations. Here they are:

```
 (setq org-latex-pdf-process 
        '("pdflatex -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode'  -bibtex -f -pdf %f"))
;;        '("latexmk -pdf %f"))                             
;;       '("xelatex %f && bibtex %f && xelatex %f && xelatex %f")
;;       '("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode %b"           
;;        "bibtex %b"
;;        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode %b"
;;        "pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode %b"))
;;       '("rubber -d --into %o %f"))
;;        (quote ("texi2dvi -p -b -V %f"))                  
;;       '("texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f"    
;;         "bibtex %b" "texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f"
;;         "texi2dvi --pdf --clean --verbose --batch %f")
```